# message.awaitReactions not detecting my reactions

Tags: discord.js

I have a discord command that requires reactions. But when I react to the message it doesn't do anything at all and when it ends it logs `Collected 0 items`.

Code:

```js
const msg = await message.reply("React to this message as quickly as you can.").catch(console.error);
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name && user.id === message.author.id;
};
            
const collector = msg.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
      
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});
    
collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? If it's v13, what are your intents?

Comment: I was originally using just "GUILD" and "GUILD_MESSAGES", but now I added the intent "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS". Thank you, I didn't know it was my intents.

Comment: I will create a real answer for this then

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Discord js reaction not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64904914/90527)", "[message event listener not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64394000/90527)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collectors require intents. You must make sure you have Guild messages intents, and guild message reaction intents. You must also make sure the message is cached.

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
  ]
})
```